# Does TexLive Portable work in different platforms (say, Mac and Windows)

Tags: texlive

I wanted to set up a portable USB installation of TeXLive (or anything else, but I figured TeXLive would be the way to go), but it would be important that it works in both Windows and Mac (and possibly Linux, but not crucial). The [relevant section of the TeXLive 2016 guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2) is not clear on this, at least to my understanding. Does anyone know the answer?